# jquery mobile backbone routing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm using jquery mobile and backbonejs.
kinda stuck with backbone routing with transition property enabled.
any suggestion will be great..

```
      define(['jquery'], function ($) {
      $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
          $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
          $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
          $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
          $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
          $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
     });
});
```

but the slide transition doesnt works.

---

the code for the router is below

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'backbone.subroute'], function($, _, Backbone) {
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        // general routes 
        '': 'defaultAction',
        'login':'login',
        'message':'message',
        'menu': 'mainMenu',
     
        // Default
        '*actions': 'defaultAction'
    }
});

var initialize = function() {

        $('.back').live('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.history.back();
            return false;
        });

    var app_router = new AppRouter;
    app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function(actions) {
        require(['views/home/register'], function(RegisterView) {
            // We have no matching route, lets display the home page 
            console.log('At defaultAction');
        var registerView = new RegisterView();
        registerView.render();
           /// this.changePage(loginView, 'slide');
        });
    });
  
     app_router.on('route:login', function(actions) {
        require(['views/home/login'], function(LoginView) {
            // We have no matching route, lets display the home page 
            console.log('At defaultAction');
        var loginView = new LoginView();
        loginView.render();
           /// this.changePage(loginView, 'slide');
        });
    });
    app_router.on('route:mainMenu', function(actions) {
        require(['views/home/menu'], function(MainMenuView) {
            console.log('At mainMenu::router');
        var mainMenuView = new MainMenuView();
        mainMenuView.render();
          //  this.changePage(mainMenuView, 'slide');
});
    });
```

can we use to cal changePage here for transition?

Comment: `mobileinit` function should be added in `<head>` after loading jQuery and before loading jQuery-Mobile scripts. and use `.on` instead of `.live` its deprecated.

Comment: @Omar the first part of the code is mobileinit function  and not working.

Answer (score 1):

This can be in a init.js file.

(function($){

```
    var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({ 
            routes: {   "": "showActivitiesPage"
            },

            showActivitiesPage: function() {                
                $.mobile.changePage("#activities", { reverse: false, changeHash: false });                          
            }           
    }); 

}(jQuery));
```

You can use change page, even when the hash listening is set to false JQM/backbone does not stop us from using the change Page and hash routing.

Check out this link it has an example in all one fiel but you can break it into controller ,model, and view

http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2011/12/introduction-to-backbonejs-with-jquery.html

In context to the above example:

Controller:

```
(function($){
$('#activities').live('pageinit', function(event){
    var activitiesListContainer = $('#activities').find(":jqmData(role='content')"),
        activitiesListView;
    exercise.initData();
    activitiesListView = new exercise.ActivityListView({collection: exercise.activities, viewContainer: activitiesListContainer});
    activitiesListView.render();
});

}(jQuery));
```

Model:

(function($){

```
exercise.Activity = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

exercise.Activities = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: exercise.Activity,
    url: "exercise.json"
});
```

}(jQuery));

View:

```
(function($){
exercise.ActivityListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        id: 'activities-list',
        attributes: {"data-role": 'listview'},

        initialize: function() {
            this.template = _.template($('#activity-list-item-template').html());
        },

        render: function() {
            var container = this.options.viewContainer,
                activities = this.collection,
                template = this.template,
                listView = $(this.el);

            $(this.el).empty();
            activities.each(function(activity){
                listView.append(template(activity.toJSON()));
            });
            container.html($(this.el));
            container.trigger('create');
            return this;
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

exercise can be global variable.

Comment: do you mean the view for this page? It can be a simple page before show or page show event with the call to its render method OR a call to its model with render in success of the model.

Comment: can u help me with some code of view to get into model or collection